# Toggle text sibilings when you slideToggle and toogle text

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, siblings

When clicking a button I would like the text to toggle and say "read more" or "read less". If I click an other button, I would like the previous button go back to its original text "read more"

HTML:

```
  <div class="accordion">
  <div class="abtn">
    <input id="A-1" type="radio" value="A">
    <label class="chars" for="A-1">A</label>
    <div class="char-more">Learn More</div>
 </div>
<div class="acontent">Hello I am content A</div>

 <div class="abtn">
     <input id="B-1" type="radio" value="B">
     <label class="chars" for="B-1">B</label>
     <div class="char-more">Learn More</div>
 </div>
 <div class="acontent">Hello I am content B</div>

 <div class="abtn">
     <input id="C-1" type="radio" value="C">
     <label class="chars" for="C-1">C</label>
     <div class="char-more">Learn More</div>
   </div>
    <div class="acontent">Hello I am content B</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
   $(".abtn .char-more").click(function(){
       $(this).closest('.abtn').nextAll(".acontent").first().slideToggle("fast")
       .siblings(".acontent:visible").slideUp('fast');
       $(this).html("Read Less");
       $(this).siblings(".char-more").html("Read More");
   });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/31/).

Comment: `char-more` aren't siblings of each other. Suggestion - wrap the button/content pairs in a wrapper and use `find()` within the wrapper. An active class when button clciked makes it easy to find the previous one to undo it

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit or provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following html structure and adding an active class to each module you can simplify how you find the previous module activated( if there is one) and also add a little style using css. It's also a little more intuitive to read than trying to debug siblings that don't exist and `nestaAll`'s

```
<div class="widgetWrap">
    <div class="abtn">
        <input id="A-1" type="radio" value="A">
        <label class="chars" for="A-1">A</label>
        <div class="char-more">Learn More</div>
     </div>
     <div class="acontent">Hello I am content A</div>
</div>
```

Your code would follow a pattern like:

```
$('.char-more').click(function(){ 
      var $prevActive=$('.activeClass');
     $prevActive.removeClass('activeClass').find('.char-more').text("Read Less");
     $prevActive.find('.acontent').slideUp(); 
     $(this).text("Read Less")
             .closest('.widgetWrap').addClass('activeClass').find('.acontent').slideDown(); 

})
```

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl, However, It doesnt function properly..Here is a Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/32/

Comment: your version doesn't add the active class, works if you use all the code and I duplicated "Read Less" in my code instead of "REad More"

Comment: If you try to toggle an individual button it does not stay open?? http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/34/

Comment: OK..so you will need to modify. I was giving example. Try with `toggleClass` and `slideToggle`. You can check the active class as one method to determine the text also

Comment: Like this? $prevActive.find('.acontent').slideToggle();
     $(this).text("Read Less")
             .closest('.widgetWrap').toggleClass('activeClass').find('.acontent').slideDown();